# In R, how do you define a new column in a df as a function of a subset of another column?

Tags: r

I have time series data in a data frame. Let's say I have one column of dates, one column of values, and I want to create a new column that is the sum of all values before the date index. Is there a better solution than using a for loop?

For example:

```
table = data.frame(date=seq(1,5),values=c(3,2,4,1,5))
table$sum = ...??
```

Comment: @HongOoi I took the liberty to expand your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use `cumsum`:

```
table = transform(table, sum_value = cumsum(values))
table
  date values sum_value
1    1      3         3
2    2      2         5
3    3      4         9
4    4      1        10
5    5      5        15
```